# Oracle ADF components experience

Tags: oracle-adf

I just saw nice little demo about Oracle ADF Rich components: http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adffaces/adffaces.html. 
Looks really cool, nice and easy but of course its just a demo :). I would like to ask if someone actually uses it for a production app, how they compare to popular open source alternatives like RichFaces or IceFaces etc.
How about a deployment to a different server than weblogic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use ADF Faces. It is quite good. They have all the basic components(input text, output text, input file, date pickers, tables, etc) and some advanced components(graphs, tree,tree tables, etc). The layout components are also good and will suffice for most use cases.

But as with any JSF component, ADF Faces Components are hard to modify. For instance, if you want to add, say, a placeholder text, on an input text then you need to resort to fragile hacks.

I would recommend ADF Faces for enterprise apps where the ability to alter and fine tune UI components is not as important as fast and low cost development.

Also, ADF Faces isn't just a component framework. It is a full ViewController framework. Check out their Task Flows and you will be amazed.

Answer (score 0):

We also use ADF Framework for our current product where we migrate our existing form based product to the new framework.

The major benefit that I'd like to point out in ADF is the way they promote declarative programming. I have to admit being a strong java developer, I have the tendency to go and add my own programmatic handling, but for someone who is used to forms, they will find it easy to learn the basics.

A strong feature that I also like to point is the way they clearly defined the MVC architecture. Model = BC, Controller = TaskFlow, View = well this one is obvious. Kudos to ADF the way they designed the taskflows as you get to have a visual representation or better put, a story of your design as well as your logic.

I am not sure about using a different server as ADF along with JDeveloper gives quite a load of features which allows you to configure directly to your server and be able to test on your intergrated server as well, with this I mean more on the security side as well as authentication piece of it. So even if you are able to migrate all the libraries needed, you might still be missing out in some of the other technologies that can be easily integrated with a weblogic server. (such as webcenter, soa etc.)